# What is the general format for a json file?

Tags: json

What is the general format for a JSON file?

Is it a dictionary with 1 key whose value is a list of dictionaries (with each  dictionary corresponding to a row)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. It can be any sort of format. see here: http://www.json.org/  - Maybe I'm misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general format of json is a key-value pair where each value may contain either a value, an array of values, or another set of key-value pairs.

As described on [json.org](http://www.json.org/):

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> - A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array.
> - An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

For example:

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification